# Conditional formatting based on neighboring cell

Tags: excel, colors, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a correlation matrix, with each correlation represented over two rows of cells - the top cell is the r value, and the bottom cell is the p value.

I want to do conditional formatting of the cell containing the r value, based on the p value that is in the cell below it (basically, I want to colour the correlations according to significance). This doubly complex, in that the conditional formatting has to be different for different rows, as I don't want the p value to be coloured based on the r value that is immediately below it... Is there any simple way to do this without having multiple data tables and cross referencing?

Comment: Conditional formatting formulas are very dependent on how your data is laid out.  Assumptions: Row 1 is a header row, "R" values start on row 2 and are on every other row (4, 6, 8, etc), "P" values start in row 3 and are on every other row (5, 7, 9, etc), and you want the conditional formatting to start in column A.  With those assumptions, this conditional format may work for you: Click cell A2 so that it is the selected cell and go to Conditional Formatting -> New Rule -> Use a Formula -> `=AND(MOD(ROW(A2),2)=0,A3="PValue1")` -> Change the "Applies to" to be your desired range (ex $A$2:$C$9)

Comment: Add additional conditional format formulas for different PValues for different colors.

Comment: @tigeravatar thank you, that did the trick! I feel kind of silly that I didn't find this myself :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a layout like this:

[image: SO40362137 example]

the cells immediately above `3` and the `5` may be formatted conditionally by selecting ColumnA and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(ISODD(ROW()),A2>2)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select choice of formatting, <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.